# Prove $(a+q*d,n) = 1$ where $q$ is the product of all primes which divide n but not a.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Let $n,a,d$ be given integers with $(a,d) = 1$.
>
> Let $m = a + q*d$ where q is the product of all primes which divide n but not a.
>
> Prove that $m \equiv a \; (mod \; d)$ and $(m,n) = 1$.

The first part follows from the rules of congruences.

$(m,n) = (a +q*d,n) = \ldots$

My idea would be to apply the Euclid property $(a,b) = (a-bq,b)$ here. However, I didn't manage to go so far with it.

Do you see alternative strategies?

**References**

Apostol, Introduction to Analytic number theory, Exercise 4.

Comment: See my answer in the linked dupe for a conceptual view based on an old idea of Stieltjes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p$ be a prime number such that $p\mid a+qd$ and that $p\mid n$. There are two possibilities:

1. $p\mid a$: Then, since $p\mid a+qd$, $p\mid qd$. So, $p\mid q$ or $p\mid d$. Both are impossible: $p\nmid q$ by the definition of $q$ and $p\nmid d$ because $p\mid a$ and $(a,d)=1$.
2. $p\nmid a$: Then, by the definition of $q$, $p\mid q$. So, $p\mid qd$. So, since we are assuming that $p\mid a+qd$, $p\mid a$, which we are assuming that it does *not* occur.